# Sed with single quotes

Tags: sed

In a script, I'm trying to replace a string, as shown below,

```
sed 's/nohup ${MY_HOME}/bin/startup.sh/su $OperationId -c '/etc/init.d/mysoftware start' /home/myfile.txt
```

and it's not working.

I'm thinking that it's because of the single quotes.

Would someone kindly help?

Comment: Use double quotes so variables can expand. Change the delimiter so it does not clash with similar characters in the file.

Comment: By "change the delimiter", instead of using `s/re/str/` use `s!re!str!` or some other character that you like.

Comment: You've got an odd number of single quotes, so it won't even parse. Start with that (possibly by pasting it into https://shellcheck.net/)

Comment: When you say "_it's not working_" think about what that actually means. What error messages (if any) do you get? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? You saw it. We didn't. Please tell us!

Comment: In addition to what the other people said: Does your file actually contain “``${MY_HOME}``”?  And do you want to actually insert “`$OperationId`”?  If so, you should consider using double quotes.  (By which I mean: you should use double quotes unless you have a good reason not to.)  Or do you want to search and replace *their **values**?* … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.